# How can I repair drywall to rehang a heavy rack in the same spot?

Tags: repair

We have a wall mount wine rack mounted to drywall, but not to the studs. The anchors have collapsed (twice) and we patched the holes.

I haven't been able to find any information on re-using the existing holes AND ensuring that the re-use can sustain the heavy weight.

How can we reinforce & re-use the existing holes to make sure there is no future collapse?

Comment: Why do you say "no studs"?  What's holding the wall up?

Comment: Welcome! Electrons are cheap, please [edit] your post to include full sentences and fully describe your situation so we can give you a good answer. The more details you can provide about the situation (but without a long story describing where each bottle came from) the better the recommendations you'll get.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure you know exactly what you are looking at.  But that didn't make it into your words.  If we're going to understand what you're looking at, we need more.

Comment: I saw your update and edited it to have some complete sentences and formatting to try to make your intent more clear. Please feel free to edit again if I've missed something.

Comment: I would venture to say that the reason the rack collapsed in the first place is that drywall really isn't designed to support heavy weight like this. The reason it collapsed the 2nd time is that your patch job, no matter how well executed, isn't as strong as "virgin" drywall and was doomed from the start. A third attempt to patch & re-hang _in the same spot and without further reinforcement_ will also be doomed to failure, thus the lack of info you've noticed on the subject. You'll probably need to move the rack to a location where bolts can be driven into studs to safely support it.

Comment: A picture of the rack, anchors, and the damaged drywall would help.

Comment: Yes pictures please.    If holes are not crazy big  toggle bolts may work

Comment: @FreeMan   Where do you buy your electrons?  They are not cheap at the bodega

Comment: You're shopping at the wrong bodega, @Kris. Mine is in a van, down by the river. ;)

Comment: Oh that guy creeps me out!    I’ll try buying in bulk at Costco

Comment: Nikegirl,  if the drywall only mount has failed twice why do you think it will not fail again ( *especially in patched/compromised holes* ? )  The proper way to address the problem is to mount the rack into structure or to a piece of wood that is mounted to structure.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply putting too much weight onto the drywall. Options:

1. Move it so that you are securing to studs in the wall
2. Remove drywall in large area and add blocks between studs. Redo drywall, patch, sand, paint, and rehang rack securing into blocking
3. Get a nice wide (atleast 1x4 or 1x6") board. Cut it long enough to be secured into at least two studs. Ideally, you want it longer by the same amount on each side of your wine rack. Place on wall and screw it into studs (2 screws per stud; 2.5" screws). You can hide the screws with either wood filler or paint depending on the look you prefer. Mount the rack to the board.

There is a possibility that you could hang it with new larger anchors, but we would need to know what exactly you are hanging and what anchoring you are using. If you used little 15lb picture frame kind of anchors, you can probably get the 75lb drywall screw-type anchors and reuse the holes, but not if the rack is going to be 100lbs when loaded.

Comment: Clearly we are not diy savvy in this regard,  hence the post. My husband’s 2nd try was with a larger anchor - we did chose the appropriate anchor for weight the first time & it did not catch. IMG_51761.jpg.

Comment: No idea how to add a pic.  There’s a window and we wanted to hang wall mounted 9 Avg sized bottles (Amazon: Sorbus Wall Mount Wine Rack 9 Bottles)

Comment: Add pics by editing you question and add them there. :)

Comment: Thank you!  l had to sign up first